# Automating The Boring Stuff With Python - Chapter 8 - Exercise - Regex Search

Tags: python-3.x, regex, search

I'm trying to complete the exercise for Chapter 8 using which takes a user supplied regular expression and uses it to search each string in each text file in a folder.

I keep getting the error:

> AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'

The code is here:

```
import os, glob, re
os.chdir("C:\Automating The Boring Stuff With Python\Chapter 8 - \
Reading and Writing Files\Practice Projects\RegexSearchTextFiles")

userRegex = re.compile(input('Enter your Regex expression :'))

for textFile in glob.glob("*.txt"):
    currentFile = open(textFile) #open the text file and assign it to a file object
    textCurrentFile = currentFile.read() #read the contents of the text file and assign to a variable
    print(textCurrentFile)
    #print(type(textCurrentFile))
    searchedText = userRegex.search(textCurrentFile)
    searchedText.group()
```

When I try this individually in the IDLE shell it works:

```
textCurrentFile = "What is life like for those left behind when the last foreign troops flew out of Afghanistan? Four people from cities and provinces around the country told the BBC they had lost basic freedoms and were struggling to survive."
>>> userRegex = re.compile(input('Enter the your Regex expression :'))
Enter the your Regex expression :troops
>>> searchedText = userRegex.search(textCurrentFile)
>>> searchedText.group()
'troops'
```

But I can't seem to make it work in the code when I run it. I'm really confused.

Thanks

Comment: If `search` returns None, that indicates that the regex search didn't find a match.

Comment: @khelwood. Thanks. Yes I know that. But I think there is something more because when I assign the text string from the text file to the variable [textCurrentFile] and create a regex object called [userRegex] with the word "troops" as input. It is clearly able to find it in the string variable when I use the group() function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are just looping across all `.txt` files, there could be files that doesn't have the word `"troops"` in it. To prove this, don't call the `.group()`, just perform:

```
print(textFile, textCurrentFile, searchedText)
```

If you see that `searchedText` is `None`, then that means the contents of `textFile` (which is `textCurrentFile`) doesn't have the word `"troops"`.

You could either:

1. Add the word troops in all `.txt` files.
2. Only select the target `.txt` files, not all.
3. Check first if if the match is found before accessing `.group()`

   ```
   print(searchedText.group() if searchedText else None)
   ```

Comment: Thanks. I will go with option 3; check first if the match is found before accessing the .group() function